# Confusion on sqlite3 struct in sqlite3 source code

Tags: c, database, sqlite

In the function

```
static int sqlite3Prepare(
    sqlite3 *db,              /* Database handle. */
    const char *zSql,         /* UTF-8 encoded SQL statement. */
    int nBytes,               /* Length of zSql in bytes. */
    int saveSqlFlag,          /* True to copy SQL text into the sqlite3_stmt */
    Vdbe *pReprepare,         /* VM being reprepared */
    sqlite3_stmt **ppStmt,    /* OUT: A pointer to the prepared statement */
    const char **pzTail       /* OUT: End of parsed string */
    ) {
     ...
     pParse = sqlite3StackAllocZero(db, sizeof(*pParse));
     ...
     assert( !db->mallocFailed );
     ...
}
```

I know sqlite3 is just a fake struct declared as

```
 typedef struct sqlite3 sqlite3;
```

without any body. I know `sqlite3 *` is usually is cast to a `Vdbe*`.

But here, `db` is of the type of `sqlite3*`, how can `db->malloFailed` exist? Why doesn't the compiler complain?

There is similar situation with `sqlite3_stmt`:

```
typedef struct sqlite3_stmt sqlite3_stmt;
```

with no body. I guess `sqlite3_stmt` is a syntax tree of parsed SQL statements. I would like to see the structure of it. However, the type is hidden so deeply using this weird pattern that I can't see what it is.

Even `Vdbe` is the same situation...

```
typedef struct Vdbe Vdbe;
```

Where on earth is the real `struct`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sqlite3` is *not* a fake struct; the `sqlite.h` file just does not define its body.

Its definition is in the `sqliteInt.h` file (which is also part of the `sqlite3.c` amalgamation):

```
/*
** Each database connection is an instance of the following structure.
*/
struct sqlite3 {
  sqlite3_vfs *pVfs;            /* OS Interface */
  struct Vdbe *pVdbe;           /* List of active virtual machines */
  CollSeq *pDfltColl;           /* The default collating sequence (BINARY) */
  ...
  u8 mallocFailed;              /* True if we have seen a malloc failure */
  ...
```

Comment: You are totally right! Awesome. So an "opaque struct" still have a body, just in some other file separated from its declaration, but the linker will find it, right?

Comment: @AlfredZhong: yes — that's how opaque types are designed to work.  As long as you don't need the size of the structure (you only have pointers to them), and you don't need to dereference any part of the structure, you don't need the structure body.  And using a named `struct Something *` is far better (type safer) than using `void *` instead.  Any one void pointer can be converted to any other (so mismatch errors can't be spotted).  But converting a `struct Something *` to a `struct AnotherThing *` requires a cast, which makes errors spottable.