# sqlite3 c++ forward declaration of struct sqlite3 leads to invalid pointer error on delete in destructor

Tags: c++, sqlite

Using Eclipse CDT on Linux. Here is the code and the warnings during compile:

```
 #ifndef DATABASECONNECTION_HPP_
#define DATABASECONNECTION_HPP_

#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class DatabaseConnection
{
private:
    sqlite3 *_database;
public:
    // constructors
    DatabaseConnection(const string &databaseURI, char mode='w');

    // destructor
    ~DatabaseConnection();
};

#endif /* DATABASECONNECTION_HPP_ */
```

the source

```
/*
 * DatabaseConnection.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Mar 31, 2015
 *      Author: Michael Wilson (mnw380@gmail.com)
 */

#include <DatabaseConnection.hpp>
#include <Exception.hpp>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <FormattedString.hpp>
#include <FileUtils.hpp>

using namespace std;

DatabaseConnection::DatabaseConnection(const string &databaseURI, char mode)
{

   if (mode != 'w' && mode != 'r')
        throw Exception("Exception DatabaseConnection::DatabaseConnection. Mode must be \'r\' or \'w\' for read/write connection mode");

    int flags = (mode == 'w') ? SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE : SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY;

    // this enables opening databases using URI
    flags |= SQLITE_OPEN_URI;

    // verify the database URI is formed correctly
    if ( !FormattedString::isFormatted(databaseURI, "file:/.*") && !FormattedString::isFormatted(databaseURI, "http:/.*") ) {
        // if not formed using standard URI syntax, then assume a file path and verify it exists
        if ( !FileUtils::Exists(databaseURI) )
            throw Exception("Exception DatabaseConnection::DatabaseConnection. File does not exist: " + databaseURI);
    }


    // returns non-zero on open error
    if ( sqlite3_open_v2(databaseURI.c_str(), &_database, flags, NULL) ) {
        ostringstream ss;
        ss << "Exception DatabaseConnection::DatabaseConnection. Error opening database " << databaseURI;
        throw Exception(ss.str());
    }
}

DatabaseConnection::~DatabaseConnection()
{
    sqlite3_close(_database);
    delete _database;
}
```

and the warnings during compile

```
g++ -I/opt/ros/indigo/include -I"/home/user/workspace/Project/include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu++11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/DatabaseConnection.d" -MT"src/DatabaseConnection.d" -o "src/DatabaseConnection.o" "../src/DatabaseConnection.cpp"
../src/DatabaseConnection.cpp: In destructor ‘DatabaseConnection::~DatabaseConnection()’:
../src/DatabaseConnection.cpp:48:9: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator: [enabled by default]
  delete _database;
         ^
../src/DatabaseConnection.cpp:48:9: warning: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct sqlite3’ [enabled by default]
In file included from /home/user/workspace/Project/include/DatabaseConnection.hpp:11:0,
                 from ../src/DatabaseConnection.cpp:8:
/usr/include/sqlite3.h:228:16: warning: forward declaration of ‘struct sqlite3’ [enabled by default]
 typedef struct sqlite3 sqlite3;
                ^
../src/DatabaseConnection.cpp:48:9: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined
  delete _database;
```

The approach is very similar to what this person has done http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/122300-sqlite-in-c/

But I want to make sure to free the database pointer 'struct sqlite3' class member

Comment: Please post `DatabaseConnection.cpp`.

Comment: `struct sqlite3 *_database;`  There is no need to say `struct` here.  Just this is all that's required `sqlite3* _database;`

Comment: Yes. That was another way that I have tried. I will post the warnings when there is no struct keyword now.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the problem is with this line in sqlite3.h 
 /usr/include/sqlite3.h:228:16: warning: forward declaration of ‘struct sqlite3’ [enabled by default]
 typedef struct sqlite3 sqlite3;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the sqlite3 API: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html

The sqlite3_close() and sqlite3_close_v2() routines are destructors for the sqlite3 object. Calls to sqlite3_close() and sqlite3_close_v2() return SQLITE_OK if the sqlite3 object is successfully destroyed and all associated resources are deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is attempting to issue a `delete _database;`, where `_database` has the type `sqlite3`.  The  problem is that the compiler does not know what a `sqlite3` is.

You forward declared what `sqlite3` is, but to issue a `delete` call requires the compile to know the **full** definition of `sqlite3`.  You did not supply the full definition of this type.

Comment: I link the sqlite3 library. I was unable to compile with the commands to open and close the database. Shouldn't that give me the definition of the sqlite struct? Also, I can step through the code up until the destructor delete statement. Doesn't this mean that the struct is defined since I call open and close?

Comment: @billz Note that those are warnings, not errors.  The problem is going to occur at runtime.

Comment: @mdude380 I'm looking stricty at the warnings -- the warnings are clear.  The compiler doesn't have the complete definition of the type at the point where `delete` is called.  Whether that header has the complete definition, I don't know -- the compiler says "no".

Comment: The sqlite3 struct is opaque. This seems to be addressing the issue but I still don't know what to do. I will try by including the file from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701298/confusion-on-sqlite3-struct-in-sqlite3-source-code

Comment: @mdude380 See here:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05288530dec33553  Similar warning.  Note that the program compiled and linked.

Comment: Yes I am beginning to understand. This is an 'opaque pointer' used to encapsulate the internals of the sqlite3 struct. Now my problem is, how do I avoid memory leak. I need to free this pointer but there is no way to know the size I guess. So, hopefully sqlite3 api has a function to free it.

Comment: Well, it probably is a "handle" to some library-created entity, and was not allocated with `new`.  Therefore calling `delete` on it was wrong.